# How to turn a column in a data frame to as POSIXct class? Only have month and year

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to convert a set of values to POSIXct class, but it keeps returning NA's. I only have the month and year, and the column is in "YYYY-MM" format.
Here is an snippet of the data I have:

```
yr_mo
"2012-08"
"2012-08"
"2012-08"
```

Here is the code I have that is returning NA's:

```
yr_mo <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x=yr_mo, format = "%Y-%m", tz= "America/Los_Angeles"))
```

I have tried different formats like `"%Y-%m-%d"` and no luck. I have also tried `as.Date` and that also did not work.

I am trying to get this data ready for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may `paste` a phantom day.

```
as.POSIXct(paste0(d$yr_mo, "-01"), tz="GMT")
# [1] "2012-08-01 GMT" "2012-08-01 GMT" "2012-08-01 GMT"
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- read.table(text='yr_mo
                "2012-08"
                "2012-08"
                "2012-08"', header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(df$yr_mo, truncated = 1)
#[1] "2012-08-01" "2012-08-01" "2012-08-01"
```

Or to convert to `POSIXct`

```
ymd_hms(df$yr_mo, truncated = 4)
#[1] "2012-08-01 UTC" "2012-08-01 UTC" "2012-08-01 UTC"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(yr_mo = c("2012-08", "2012-08", "2012-08")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```